# iOS Safe Area margin not extending to bottom of navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, storyboard, constraints, safearealayoutguide

Edit - This was marked as duplicate.  While the solution was the same in the answer I got linked to, the symptom I was looking to fix was not, and I did not find it mentioned after hours of research.

I can't for the life of me get this stupid iphone x stuff to work right.

I have a view, which is meant to be pressed up right under the navigation bar. Works fine on any non-iphone x device. However, iPhone x has a fair gap (at least 20+ pts) between the top of this view and the navigation bar when I constrain it to either the top of the safe area, or the top margin of the superview (main view of the storyboard view controller) with safe area relative margins turned on.

If I turn those safe area relative margins off for the main view, the view I'm trying to constrain to the bottom of the navigation bar is underneath the navigation bar, all the way at the top of the screen.

I have this view set to allow the view to extend under the navigation bar, as it's translucent and has a map that moves underneath. I'd like to keep this effect if possible.

As an aside, I wonder if it's perhaps related, but I haven't been able to get my iPhone x simulator to extend the edges of any view past the safe area.  I always have a big black bar at the top and bottom, even though on my storyboard it shows the backgrounds extending all the way to the proper edges.  So, my *storyboard* is displaying things properly, even this one view pressed up against the navigation bar that I'm having issues with.  But the simulator won't extend any view past the safe area, and this particular view that is meant to appear attached to the navigation bar is significantly lower.

Any tips or requests for information I could provide to help solve this issue?

Thanks

Edit - At the portion of [this link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/) that says

> Check that your code handles a different screen aspect ratio. Many apps position content based on a particular width, height, or aspect ratio. Verify that your content scales and is positioned correctly.

My app is ALWAYS showing up like the example on the right.  There is always a big ugly black bar above all navigation controllers, or even screens with no navigation controller and a background image.  The storyboard shows these like the image on the left that I'm supposed to be aiming for, but running the simulator never reflects this.  Am I Just experiencing a simulator bug?

Comment: My experience with the simulator is not reflective of this at all.  *Nothing* extends to the top corners, there is a big black bar above my navigation bars, even removing the safe area check on the main view, the storyboard will show my background image extending all the way to the edge of the screen but running the simulator it's cut off.  Adding an edit to the bottom of my post to provide an example.

Comment: I strongly suggest you adopt a launch storyboard rather than launch images to avoid these sorts of issues.

Comment: I had heard of the launch storyboard but this is the first time I've heard it has any relation to this issue, despite hours of research.  Huh.  I'll look into implementing that and report back if it resolves this.  I'll start searching on my own but if you happen to have a link on how to convert, feel free to drop it!

Comment: Paulw11 , This was the magic answer, thanks.